# Square-constructing program returns wrong measures

Tags: java

So I have to write a program inheriting the `Rectangle` class that asks for the center of the Square and the side length.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Square extends Rectangle {
    /** Constructs a square given the center and side length
     * @param centerX
     * @param centerY
     * @param side
     */
    public Square(int centerX, int centerY, int side) {
        square = new Rectangle();
        square.setLocation(centerX - side / 2, centerY - side / 2);
        square.setSize(side, side);
    }

    /** Returns the area of the square
     * @return area
     */
    public double getArea() {
        return (square.getWidth() * square.getWidth());
    }

    private Rectangle square;
}
```

This is the test program:

```
public class SquareTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square square = new Square(50, 50, 100);
        System.out.println(square.toString());
        System.out.println("Area: " + square.getArea());
    }
}
```

While it should return:

```
Square[x=0,y=0,width=100,height=100]
Area: 10000.0
```

The program returns this instead:

```
Square[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]
Area: 10000.0
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't give the Square class a Rectangle field, but instead have this class use it's own inner innate Rectangleness. Remember that it itself **is** a Rectangle since it inherits from this class.

In other words, get rid of this line/field:

```
private Rectangle square;
```

And in the constructor, be sure to call the `super` constructor to help you with this.

```
public class Square extends Rectangle
{
    /** Constructs a square given the center and side length
    @param centerX
    @param centerY
    @param side
    */
    public Square(int centerX, int centerY, int side)
    {
        super(???);

        // .... ???
    }
```

Note that we don't have a copy of your Rectangle code and so I cannot tell you exactly what the super call should look like, but I'm sure that you can figure this out.

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot that I should use the super constructor for the subclass. Now it works well!